# Return values from a mocha test exported by a separate module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, nodeunit

I have a REST API and one of my test requires certain resources to have been created by another API... The example below demonstrates the pattern.. Questions are

1. Is this an appropriate patter to use with Mocha
2. If so, how would you recommend I get the ID of the created user into my account test case?
3. Other recommended approaches?

   ```
   userTest.js

   exports.createAdminUser = function(done) {
       request.post( ... );
       expect(res.location).to.eql(...);
       // Now I've created an admin user
   };

   describe('User Tests', function() {

       it('creates an admin user', createAdminUser);
       it('modifies the admin user', ...);
       ...
   }
   ```

This I have another test for accounts, which must have a user setup.  I don't want to do this work again for each of these types of dependent tests

```
Accounts Test
-------------

var userTests = require('../users/userTest.js');

describe('Account Tests', function() {

    it('creates an admin user to prime the database', userTests.createAdminUser);

    it('creates a checking account', function(done){
        // Here I need to know the ID of the admin user to use in my POST req.
    });
}
```

Comment: try looking the mocha documentation for `beforeEach()` and `afterEach` ..since this is a REST API try also using `supertest` module for making http requests and testing the whole thing.

Comment: I'm using superagent for now to make requests.. I'll look into supertest.

So I could use the beforeEach() to execute those create methods in the other test but I want access to their variables (such as the ID that is created, so I can use them)... In the other tests, those are captured outside the test method, as global variables, but I don't have access to those in the exported module.

Comment: its easier since it has `.expect()` for assertions and `.end(fn)` to further work with the response of the http request. 

There is no need to export global variables and other stuff.. usually in rest apis the ID is also exposed to response body. 
So you can work from there.

Comment: The ID is indeed in the response body (and location), so my testA module gets the ID when it runs, but I need that use that variable in testB (in the above example.  if the ID is captured within userTests.createAdminUser, it won't be accessiable by the function defined for it('creates a checking account', function(done) <--

Comment: these should be REST API calls and not in-code calls every request can do multiple actions and output the response. you could structure the testing requests inside callbacks to achieve the result.

Comment: They actually already are REST calls, but I don't want to rewrite them in each test suite just so I can access their responses locally in my suite.  Since somebody already wrote the UserTest, I'd just like to run it as a precondition to my Account Test (using before or beforeEach might be appropriate), but I then will have to write a get request to get the IDs of those that were created... that's what I'm trying to avoid (somebody has already written those GETs tests as well.